# Exceeding spark.akka.frameSize when saving Word2VecModel

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I am using Spark's `Word2Vec` to train some word vectors. The training is essentially working but when it comes to saving the model I am getting a `org.apache.spark.SparkException` saying:

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 1278:0 was 1073394582 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.akka.frameSize (134217728 bytes) - reserved (204800 bytes). Consider increasing spark.akka.frameSize or using broadcast variables for large values.

The stack trace points at line 190, but there is a chance that I changed some of the code and I think it's actually line 196 that causes the problem:

```scala
190: val sizeGb = (model.getVectors.size * arguments.getVectorSize * 4.0)/(1024*1024*1024.0);
191: 
192: println("Final vocabulary word count: " + model.getVectors.size)
193: println("Output file size:      ~ " + f"$sizeGb%1.4f" + " GB")
154: println("Saving model to " + outputFilePath)
195:
196: model.save(sc, outputFilePath)
```

From my own output I got an estimated model size of

```scala
// (vocab-size * vector-size * 4)/(1024^3) = ~ 0.9767 GB
val sizeGb = (model.getVectors.size * arguments.getVectorSize * 4.0)/(1024*1024*1024.0);
```

which comes close to 1073394582 bytes.
The stack trace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 1278:0 was 1073394582 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.akka.frameSize (134217728 bytes) - reserved (204800 bytes). Consider increasing spark.akka.frameSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2VecModel$SaveLoadV1_0$.save(Word2Vec.scala:617)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2VecModel.save(Word2Vec.scala:489)
    at masterthesis.code.wordvectors.Word2VecOnCluster$.main(Word2VecOnCluster.scala:190)
    at masterthesis.code.wordvectors.Word2VecOnCluster.main(Word2VecOnCluster.scala)
```

The error message is clear but I am not sure what I can do about this. On the other hand I have already saved models larger than 125MB (our default frame size) and Spark didn't complain..

I am not sure what I can do about this..

Comment: did u find a solution on it?

Answer (score -1):

Just like your error Log suggests there are two ways of Doing this

- Either by increasing the `spark.akka.frameSize`, the default size is 128MB.

  You can refer to the [Network Configuration Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking) Or if your using a standalone shell you can set it passing the argument `--driver-java-options "-Dspark.akka.frameSize=128"`
- Or by using [broadcast variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) for large values.

Comment: Setting the `frameSize` appears to be a bad solution because it is limitted to `2047 MB`. The actual question here is why `Word2VecModel#save()` is actually not capable to do this on its own actually?