# Serialized task exceeds max allowed, Spark - Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

So I'm working with java to deploy in spark, this was my original code:

```
List<Float> data = some_data;
JavaRDD<Float> dataAsRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(data);
JavaRDD<Float> dataWithoutNaN = dataAsRDD.filter(number -> !number.isNaN());
JavaDoubleRDD dataAsDouble = dataWithoutNaN.mapToDouble(number -> (double) number);
logger.info("\t\t\tMean: " + dataAsDouble.mean());
```

So, this can run in apache-spark stand alone mode with warning but in cluster mode keeps runing into an error: (line 86 is *dataAsDouble.mean()*)

```
17/01/06 17:54:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: mean at Cluster.java:86, took 12.678086 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 0:0 was 45337325 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.akka.frameSize (10485760 bytes) - reserved (204800 bytes). Consider increasing spark.akka.frameSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
```

I follow the instructions suggested in the exception, [Exceeding spark.akka.frameSize when saving Word2VecModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692386/exceeding-spark-akka-framesize-when-saving-word2vecmodel) and [Spark broadcast error: exceeds spark.akka.frameSize Consider using broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218472/spark-broadcast-error-exceeds-spark-akka-framesize-consider-using-broadcast), I used a broadcast variable:

```
List<Float> dataAsList = some_data;
Broadcast<List<Float>> broadcast = javaSparkContext.broadcast(dataAsList);
JavaRDD<Float> dataAsRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(broadcast.value());
JavaRDD<Float> dataWithoutNaN = dataAsRDD.filter(number -> !number.isNaN());
JavaDoubleRDD dataAsDouble = dataWithoutNaN.mapToDouble(number -> (double) number);
logger.info("\t\t\tMean: " + dataAsDouble.mean());
```

But I keep runing in the same error, ¿what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the point of using Spark, when you're just parallelizing some data structure and invoke `mean` method on that structure? Wouldn't it be simpler to calculate the mean using regular Java operations?

Comment: Hi @PawełJurczenko, I'm building a POC using [SparkTS](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/spark-ts-a-new-library-for-analyzing-time-series-data-with-apache-spark/) and my code it's a little bit more complicated but I used `mean` to exemplify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using broadcasts in a wrong way. Those should not be converted to RDD immediately (as you do in `javaSparkContext.parallelize(broadcast.value())`), but they should be passed to operations on RDD. Since you're parallelizing some data structure only to calculate its mean (I assume you're just experimenting with Spark), you can't achieve that using broadcasts. As the message warning says, you have an alternative solution: increasing `spark.akka.frameSize`. This can be achieved by passing this to your spark-shell/spark-submit:

```
--conf spark.akka.frameSize=64
```

which would increase the frame size to 64 MB.

Comment: Hi @PawelJurczenko, ¿could you be a little more specific about _they should be passed to operations on RDD_, the code I wrote was based on http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: Broadcasts should be passed to operations like filter, map, flatMap etc. For example you can broadcast an array of integers (the type would be `Broadcast<int[]>`) and you can use it inside the filter operation (which could for example check if currently processed element is present in the broadcasted array)